# Substract two datatable values

Tags: c#, sql, pivot

I have 2 datatables with same schema. I would like to subtract the values from 2 datatables. 
Please note that I am getting the datatable from database using pivot query.
I am looking for best solution for my problem.

For example I have below datatables

```
Datatable 1
Date    Amount1 Amount2 Amount3
01/01/2019  45  21  21
02/01/2019  55  23  23
03/01/2019  458 3   23
04/01/2019  43  3   4
05/01/2019  534 45  67
06/01/2019  34  67  78
07/01/2019  45  7   56
08/01/2019  456 78  6

Datatable 2
Date    Amount1 Amount2 Amount3
01/01/2019  52  2   23
02/01/2019  65  3   23
03/01/2019  7   3   23
04/01/2019  52  2   3
05/01/2019  42  45  67
06/01/2019  54  3   78
07/01/2019  45  7   234
08/01/2019  54  3   24
```

My expected output should be

```
Date    Amount1 Amount2 Amount3
01/01/2019  -7  19  -2
02/01/2019  -10 20  0
03/01/2019  451 0   0
04/01/2019  -9  1   1
05/01/2019  492 0   0
06/01/2019  -20 64  0
07/01/2019  0   0   -178
08/01/2019  402 75  -18
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result1 = (from c in dt.AsEnumerable()
                          join c2 in dt1.AsEnumerable() on c.Field<DataColumn>("Date") equals c2.Field<DataColumn>("Date")
                          select new
                          {
                              Date = c.Field<DataColumn>("Date"),
                              Amount1 = Convert.ToInt32(c.Field<DataColumn>("Amount1")) - Convert.ToInt32(c2.Field<DataColumn>("Amount1")),
                              Amount2 = Convert.ToInt32(c.Field<DataColumn>("Amount2")) - Convert.ToInt32(c2.Field<DataColumn>("Amount2")),
                              Amount3 = Convert.ToInt32(c.Field<DataColumn>("Amount3")) - Convert.ToInt32(c2.Field<DataColumn>("Amount3")),
                          }).ToList();
```

After converting into list. You need to convert List into DataTable. I am writing the code of converting datatable into list. Pass this result1 variable to  ToDataTable method

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
{
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);

       PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
        {

            var type = (prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType && prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>) ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) : prop.PropertyType);

            dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, type);
        }
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
           var values = new object[Props.Length];
           for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
           {

                values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
           }
           dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
      }

      return dataTable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have attached a picture of what I understand are the tables you would like to substract and the final result. Have you considered the posibility to create a view on the database and just query the results? I have left below some SQL code (SQL Server 2012) you can use to unpivot the source tables, get the result and pivot the table again. Your sources tables are p1 and p2. [Data source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjGvX.jpg)

SELECT TheDate,[dateamount1] as Dateamount1, [dateamount2] as Dateamount2, [dateamount3] as Dateamount3
FROM
(
SELECT unP1.date as TheDate, unp1.Concept as TheConcept, unp1.orders-unp2.orders as TheDiff FROM
(
SELECT Date, Concept, Orders 
FROM
   (SELECT Date, dateamount1, dateamount2, dateamount3
   FROM dbo.p1) as P1u
UNPIVOT
   (Orders FOR Concept IN
      (dateamount1, dateamount2, dateamount3)
)AS uP1) AS unP1
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT Date, Concept, Orders 
FROM
   (SELECT Date, dateamount1, dateamount2, dateamount3
   FROM dbo.p2) as P1u
UNPIVOT
   (Orders FOR Concept IN
      (dateamount1, dateamount2, dateamount3)
)AS uP2) AS unP2
ON unP1.date = unp2.date and unp1.Concept = unp2.Concept) p
PIVOT
(SUM(TheDiff)
FOR TheConcept in
([dateamount1], [dateamount2] , [dateamount3] ) ) as theResult

Hope it helps.